# PHP 7.0 - ext/mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Which PHP version mssql_connect function has been deprecated or removed the lamp environment?

Okay I'm trying to run a legacy application in PHP 7.0:

```
yum install php70w php70w-opcache php70w-Common php70w-pdo php70w-mssql
```

and I get the error message :

```
Uncaught error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect().
```

I found only a link in the wiki about it and nothing in the documentation.

[Removal of dead sapis and exts](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/removal_of_dead_sapis_and_exts)

I believe I'll have to refactor for PDO, but not everything works well with PDO and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

The `mssql_` library has been removed in PHP7, as you know.

Instead, Microsoft will be officially supporting connections through the `sqlsrv` library.

However, support for `sqlsrv` in PHP7 has not been fully completed yet, and as such, Microsoft released a statement saying they intend to have it out around Q1 of FY 2016.

This means that your legacy application cannot be ported yet. However, keep a look out, as they should be coming *relatively* soon.

Comment: sqlsrv only works in Windows, it isn't an alternative on LAMP environment.

Comment: @edercortes You're not wrong at all, I'm just stating the facts. PHP7 is early in development still and much is super immature at this point. Just letting you know that you won't be able to port this legacy application as it stands.